# Indexing date fields with format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" into ElasticSearch 2.2.1

Tags: java, date, datetime, elasticsearch, jodatime

Has anyone been able to index a date field with the format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" into ElasticSearch 2.2.1?

My mapping as as follows:

`"_updated_at": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "Y-MM-d' 'H:m:ss"
    }`

When I attempt to index, I get this error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: MapperParsingException[failed to parse [doc._created_at]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: "2015-10-03 13:56:21" is malformed at " 13:56:21"];`

This seems crazy, as the above date format is very common.

Is there any workaround (apart from substituting the space with a 'T')??

Answer (score 1):

Please update your mapping to

"_updated_at": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    }

Also while passing the date to ES, make sure that you are using the "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" as your dateformat

Comment: Thanks for the super-quick response. Are you saying that I cannot start with the year ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") ?

Comment: You can do that, but both the date format in mapping and the value should have same date format

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do the same mapping for `_created_at` in addition to `_updated_at`:

```
"_created_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "Y-MM-d' 'H:m:ss"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I had to use a _default mapping - which ensured that my date fields (_created_at, _updated_at and _deleted_at) were set to the correct format. Initially I was only setting one type.

Here is my corrected mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default": {
      "properties": {
        "doc": {
          "properties": {
            "_created_at": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "Y-MM-d' 'H:m:ss"
            },
            "_deleted_at": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "Y-MM-d' 'H:m:ss"
            },
            "_updated_at": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "Y-MM-d' 'H:m:ss"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```